# Is Visual SVN 3.8.4 is compatible with windows server 2019?

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server

I am upgrading windows server 2012 to Windows server 2019. Currently i am using visual server 3.8.4 on Windows Server 2012.

My question is visual server 3.8.4 is compatible with Windows Server 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Although VisualSVN Server version 3.8.x should work with Windows Server 2019, it has been out of support for years.

You should **upgrade to the latest version** which is now VisualSVN Server 5.3.x.